# retrieve column data from an INNER JOINED table?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to select all (*) the data columns on one table accompanied by INNER JOINing another table to get the menu item name. Please have a look at my query

```
string query = "SELECT ol.*, m.menu_name " +
                "FROM orderlist ol " +
                "INNER JOIN menudb m " +
                "ON m.menu_ID = ol.menu_ID " +
                "WHERE ol.order_ID = @orderID";
```

I can't seem to get the `m.menu_name` when I retrieve it using `dr["menu_name"].ToString()`

Any ideas why?

orderlist Table Columns

`orderlist_ID` `order_ID` `menu_ID` `order_quantity`

menudb Table Columns

`menu_ID` `menu_name` `menu_price` `menu_description` `menu_category` `menu_status`

Comment: can you show the structure of the two tables: `orderlist` and `menudb`?

Comment: I got it guyss :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems in your query.

**First**, you have a syntax error due to lack of spaces between keywords.

```
"ON m.menu_ID = ol.menu_ID" +     // << HERE
"WHERE ol.order_ID = '@orderID'";
```

you should have add an extra space after `ol.menu_ID`

```
"ON m.menu_ID = ol.menu_ID " +
"WHERE ol.order_ID = '@orderID'";
```

**Second**, if you parameterized the query, you should not wrap the parameter with a single quote. This causes to be a string and not a parameter anymore.

```
"WHERE ol.order_ID = @orderID"; // remove single quote
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed s space after `ol.menu_ID`.

```
"ON m.menu_ID = ol.menu_ID "+
```